# Excel/Powerpoint Office Interop - Copy chart from Excel Sheet to Powerpoint Slide

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop, excel-interop

I have an Excel workbook with multiple charts inside. I have created a for loop that gets the charts in each sheet. This works without error.

The issues I am having are I cannot import multiple charts, only one and it imports as a picture not a chart.

When I try to import multiple charts, I get a `COMException` on this line:

```
objChart.Copy();
```

Full error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

Here Is my full method:

```
public int ImportExcelChartsFromWorkbookToSlides(int startingSlideIndex, string workbookPath, string[] slideTitles)
{
    int slideIndex = startingSlideIndex;
    int titleIndex = 0;
    EXCL.Application objExclApp = new EXCL.Application();
    EXCL.Workbook objWorkbook = objExclApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, Editable: false);
    foreach (EXCL.Worksheet objSheet in objWorkbook.Worksheets)
    {
        foreach (EXCL.ChartObject objChart in objSheet.ChartObjects())
        {
            AddTitleOnlySlide(slideIndex);
            SetTitleOnlySlideTitle(slideTitles[titleIndex]);

            // Copy Chart from Sheet to Slide
            objChart.Copy();

            PPT.ShapeRange objShapeRange = objSlide.Shapes.Paste();

            // TODO PARAMETER
            objShapeRange.Left = 10;
            objShapeRange.Top = 100;

            slideIndex++;
            titleIndex++;
        }
    }
    return slideIndex;
}
```

Does anyone see any issues with this code?

***UPDATE***

If I change this line:

```
objChart.Copy();
```

to this:

```
objChart.CopyPicture();
```

I have no issues.. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by using `objChart.CopyPicture();` but this was [causing crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46770997/1888770) for some users so I ended up doing this:

```
string chartPath = $@"{workbookPath.Substring(0, workbookPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)}{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.png";
objChart.Chart.Export(chartPath, "PNG", false);
objSlide.Shapes.AddPicture2(chartPath, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, chartPosLeft, chartPosTop, compress: MsoPictureCompress.msoPictureCompressFalse);
```